# popoverControllerDidDismissPopover method is not called

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller

In my application I have a `presentViewController`, and inside it I have a button that opens a popover. In this popover I have a barButtonItem to save de data of this popover. I would like that when the user taps outside of the popover, the data could be saved too.
I've tried to use the `popoverControllerDidDismissPopover` method in the `presentViewController` view. I have the delegate but when I tap outside of the popover this method is not called.

What can I do?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

Add this line of code while adding popOver:

```
 popover.delegate = self;
```

Also register popOverDelegate in .h file where u present your popOver COntroller

```
@interface yourViewController : UIViewController<UIPopoverControllerDelegate>
```

Comment: I have the delegate in h and i do the  popover.delegate = self; when i call the popover

Answer (score 5):

**Please, pay attention to docs!**

"Called on the delegate when the user has taken action to dismiss the popover.
***This is not called when the popover is dismissed programmatically.***"

It was my case because my popover was closing on button tap with this method:

```
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably already solved it, but I just faced the same problem. I'm holding a instance of `UIPopoverController` in my Viewcontroller and had it this way:

```
self.popover.delegate = self;
self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:wgtvc];
```

of course this doesn't work because I'm initializing the `UIPopoverController` AFTER setting the delegate, which overrides the delegate setting. So the correct way is to FIRST initialize the UIPopovercontroller and THEN setting the delegate

```
self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:wgtvc];
self.popover.delegate = self;
```

Maybe you are reinitializing your `UIPopoverController` somewhere - just set the delegate again after reinitializing.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I solved it by handling it different for iOS8.

**Presentation code**

```
    UIViewController *searchViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    [[searchViewController view] addSubview:_searchOptions];
    [searchViewController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationPopover];
    [searchViewController setPreferredContentSize:CGSizeMake(500, 400)];

    [_searchOptions setHidden:NO];
    [_searchOptions setFrame:[[searchViewController view] bounds]];
    [_searchOptions setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidthAndHeight];

    if (CRIdiomToolsIsIOS8OrHigher())
    {
        UIPopoverPresentationController *popOverPresentationController = [searchViewController popoverPresentationController];

        [popOverPresentationController setDelegate:self];
        [popOverPresentationController setSourceView:[_searchOptionsButton disclosureView]];
        [popOverPresentationController setSourceRect:[[_searchOptionsButton disclosureView] bounds]];

        [self presentViewController:searchViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        UIPopoverController *popOverControler = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:searchViewController];

        [popOverControler setDelegate:self];
        [popOverControler setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(500, 400)];

        [popOverControler presentPopoverFromRect:[[_searchOptionsButton disclosureView] bounds] inView:[_searchOptionsButton disclosureView] permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp|UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft animated:YES];
    }
```

**Delegate calls**

```
#pragma mark Delegate Methods: UIPopoverControllerDelegate

- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    [self showSearchOptions:NO animated:YES];
}

#pragma mark Delegate Methods: UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate

- (void)popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverPresentationController *)popoverPresentationController
{
    [self showSearchOptions:NO animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. You will need to retain the popover object, that way the delegate method gets called. Its strange but it works.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPopoverController *popupObject;

UIPopoverController *popup = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:viewController];
popup.delegate = self;
[popup presentPopoverFromRect:presentationRect inView:self permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
self.popupObject = popup; //Retained


-(void) popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
  //Do whatever operation you need to perform
  self.popupObject = nil; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this questions is old but hopefully it helps someone out there...

The issue is in the initialization of your popover controller. If you have established the popover segue in the storyboard you need to have a reference to this popover in order for the delegate to be called when it is dismissed.

In your prepare for segue method:

Instead of:

```
    self.popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:segue.destinationViewController];
    self.popoverController.delegate = self;
```

You need:

```
   self.popoverController = [(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue popoverController];
    self.popoverController.delegate = self;
```

Then make sure to correctly handle if the when the popover should appear in

- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender